# How do I find-out what versions of Active Directory I am connecting to when using LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I would like to know what version of AD I am connecting to when using LDAP to connect to an Active Directory.

How can I do this?

I am using python3-ldap pure-python module to connect to LDAP, but I guess that's not so important. Maybe there is a special object that I need to query?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at RootDSE on a domain controller, you can look at three attributes - `domainControllerFunctionality`, `domainFunctionality`, and `forestFunctionality`. Those will tell you the OS of the DC, and the functional levels of the domain and forest, respectively.

That said, what is it you're trying to accomplish here? This might not be the best approach.